# JMS with multiples Glassfish - How to send and receive messages to remote Topic/Queue

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe, glassfish-4.1

I'm new with JMS and Glassfish. I looked for information but I have not been able to have multiple glassfish servers send and receive messages to a queue hosted on one of those servers.

Is it possible for multiple servers to subscribe to a remote topic to receive the same messages?

Comment: Have you by any chance found any good resources to answer this question?

Comment: @MichaelRemijan yes, I resolved.